# Making an new array only out of the values that are the same in two other arrays - R

Tags: r

Say you have the following two arrays:

```
Array1 = c(1,  2,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19)
Array2 = c(1, 3, 5,  9, 11, 14, 18)
```

Now say you want to make a new array which only holds the values that are the same between Array1 and Array2:

```
NewArray = c(1, 9, 11, 14, 18)
```

How does one do this without having to manually scan each Array1 and Array2 to construct NewArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/R/intersect.html):

```
Array1 = c(1,  2,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19)
Array2 = c(1, 3, 5,  9, 11, 14, 18)
NewArray = intersect(Array1, Array2)
```